# Optimize Laravel Eloquent whereHas() query - very slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.4

I have 3 models: Order, OrderLine and Product.

Order hasMany() OrderLines
OrderLine hasOne() Product via the product_id in the OrderLine model (I have properly indexed this, at least I think!)

My requirement is to retrieve all Orders and OrderLines where the Product is for a certain brand name.

Here is my eloquent query. I know the query works but it seems to infinitely run when put on a large dataset (circa 10,000 Orders, 12,000 OrderLines/Products)

```
$orders = Order::whereBetween('order_date', [$this->start_date,$this->end_date])
    ->whereHas('lines', function ($q1){
        $q1->whereHas('product', function ($q2){
            $q2->where('brand', 'Brands>SanDisk');
        });
    })->with('lines')->with('lines.product')->get()->toArray();
```

This produces the following SQL when debugging via toSql() method.

```
select
   *
from `orders`
where
   `order_date` between ? and ? 
and
  exists (select * from `order_lines` where `orders`.`id` =`order_lines`.`order_id` 
and
  exists (select * from `products` where `order_lines`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `brand` = ?))
```

My 3 migrations to create the tables are as follows (I have removed anything except keys for simplicity):

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});

Schema::create('order_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('product_id');
    $table->integer('order_id');
});

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

I then added the following index:

```
Schema::table('order_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->change();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
});
```

Results of EXPLAIN syntax as follows:

```
1   PRIMARY orders  ALL                 91886   Using where 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  order_lines ALL                 93166   Using where 
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  products    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mymemory_main.order_lines.product_id    1   Using where
```

Comment: Optimise questions should include the CREATE TABLE structure(s) off the tables orders, order_lines and products.. And a EXPLAIN [query] output...

Comment: You'll probably want to examine the subqueries in a mysql console with the `EXPLAIN` syntax, but I'd at least recommend indexes on `order_lines.order_id` and `order_lines.product_id`

Comment: Could you please show how you indexed the tables?

Comment: the generated SQL query is very very badly generated.. the SQL is generated wil take two correlated subqueries. And correlated subqueries are the worst kind qua performance.

Comment: @Quasdunk I have added the migration information showing the tables

Comment: You're using the `order_date` but it doesn't seem to be indexed. Also I think the `brand` should be indexed as well.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added the results of the EXPLAIN in the body of the question

Comment: orders.date should be indexed... orders.id should be indexed....  order_lines.order_id should be indexed.... products.id should be indexed.  for the best speeds

Comment: if you run the query directly on console spend the same time?

Comment: @RaymondNijland `orders.id`, `order_lines.order_id` and `products.id` are already indexed - Laravel does that automatically. So it's just the `orders.date` and `products.brand`.

Comment: `orders.id` and `products.id` would automatically be indexed as they're auto-increment fields. `order_lines.order_id` would not be.

Comment: @aynber right, I missed that one. `order_lines.product_id` is indexed by the foreign key statement though.

Comment: Thanks guys I am trying to setup the indexes now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- **[mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery: Convert has() and whereHas() constraints to non-dependent subqueries.](https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery)**
- [mpyw/eloquent-has-by-join: Convert has() and whereHas() constraints to join() ones for single-result relations.](https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-join)

```php
$orders = Order::query()
    ->whereBetween('order_date', [$this->start_date, $this->end_date])
    ->hasByNonDependentSubquery('lines.product', null, function ($q) {
        $q->where('brand', 'Brands>SanDisk');
    })
    ->with('lines.product')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

That's all. Happy Eloquent Life!